# Using Microsoft Solver Foundation to solve a linear programming task requiring thousands of data points

Tags: linear-programming, ms-solver-foundation

Using Microsoft Solver Foundation,I am trying to solve a linear program of the form Ax <= b where A is a matrix containing thousands of data points.

I know that I can new up a Model object and then use the AddConstraint method to add constraints in equation form. However putting those equations together where each contains thousands of variables is just not possible. I looked at the Model Class and can not find a way to just give it the matrix and other info.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make `A` a parameter and bind data to it. Warning: Microsoft Solver Foundation has been discontinued a while ago, so you are advised to consider an alternative modeling system.

Comment: Could you recommend any alternative modeling system? MSF had a pretty neat syntax...